# Content is hiding after few seconds after tab clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code this code is working fine but i dont know where is some mistake after few seconds content is hiding no content is displaying when i click to "listl" tab

```
  function explode(){
        jQuery( ".view-id-category_view.view-display-id-page" ).hide();
    }
    setTimeout(explode, 2000);
    jQuery( "#listl" ).click(function( ) {
        jQuery( ".view-id-category_view.view-display-id-page" ).show(); 
    });
    jQuery( "#listr" ).click(function( ) {
        jQuery( ".view-id-category_view.view-display-id-page" ).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: "After few seconds content is hiding": `setTimeout(explode, 2000);`?

Comment: explain setTimeout(explode, 2000); line in your code why it is there ?

Comment: You should probably show your HTML also so we can rule out any issues there regarding: "no content is displaying when i click to "listl" tab".

Comment: this code i copied from somewhere else i am not jquery ui developer i am drupal developer ...so dnt knw much abt javascript

Comment: setTimeout(explode, 2000) by using this i have to hide particular content of  page under "listr" tab ...and same hidden content i have to show on clicking "listl" tab